# Spring JPA repositary save for ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, testing, spring-data-jpa

I have `Transaction` and `Account` entities. From those two entities, I have created `transaction_account_map` join table by using `@ManyToMany` relationship. Whenever I save the transaction on my db, the data is not being written on join table.

The Account entity

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class Account {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,generator = "account_sequence")
@Column(unique = true)
private Long accountNumber;

@Column(nullable = false)
private float balanceAccount;

@OneToOne(
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
    optional = false)
@JoinColumn(
        name = "client_id",
        referencedColumnName = "clientId"
)
private Client client;
```

The Transaction entity

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class Transaction {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name ="transaction_sequence",
        sequenceName = "transaction_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,generator = "transaction_sequence")
private Long transactionId;

@Column(nullable = false)
private float transactionAmount;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date date;

@ManyToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY

)
@JoinTable(
        name = "transaction_account_map",
        joinColumns =
                {
                        @JoinColumn(
                                name = "transaction_id",
                                referencedColumnName = "transactionId"
                        )
                },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "account_number",
                referencedColumnName = "accountNumber")
        }
)
private List<Account> accounts;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String description;

}
```

[Join table transaction_account_map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGSJL.png) Image.

The TransactionRepositaryTest method

```
@Test
public void saveTransaction()
{
    Long accountNumber = 101L;
    Account account = accountRepositary.findByAccountNumber(accountNumber);
    List<Account> accounts = Arrays.asList(account);

    Transaction transaction = Transaction.builder()
            .transactionAmount(-36)
            .description("test")
            .accounts(accounts)
            .build();

    transactionRepositary.save(transaction);
}
```

The only solution which comes into my mind was to write in `@ManyToMany` annotation `mappedBy = "transaction"` but this didn't resolve my issue. I searched but couln't find any solution to this.

Comment: Using of ManyToMany relationship is bad practice. Try to avoid it.

Comment: So What would you advice me instead?